What's exact result of the integral related to Bessel's function?
I want to find the form of the following integral, which I've seen typically extend $\mbox{from}~0~\mbox{to}~\infty$ and are represented using Bessel Functions:

However, when the limit is a constant other than infinity, I'm unsure how to handle it.
The integral is:
$\displaystyle
\int_{k}^{\infty} \exp\left(\frac{k_1}{x}+k_2x\right)\, \text{d}x
$
where $k>0$ and $k_1$, $k_2$ are constants.


The result likely will require incomplete Bessel functions, which are not usually seen as standard functions, or a double hypergeometric sum like these functions

The substitution $x=ku$ renders the integral as $k\int_1^\infty \exp[(k_1/k)x^{-1}+k_2 k]~du$. Introducing $k_1'=k_1/k$ and $k_2'=k_2 k$ then effectively eliminates $k$ from the integral. Hence there is no loss in generality to take $k=1$.
